# PL/SQL Procedure: How return a select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, plsql

I want to create a **stored procedure** on **ORACLE database server** and my problem is that, I don't know how can I return a select statement .

Here is the logic, which should within the procedure:

Input paramters: filter1 (int), filter2 (string)

```
with cte as
(
    select  val1, val2, stddev(val3) from tab1 where parameter1 = filter1 and paramter = filter1 group by val 1, val2
)
 SELECT cte.*,
    round(some calculation) as final_results FROM cte
```

Afterwards I want to use this procedure in a MS asp.net application, with help of the MS ADO.net and MS Entity Framework 4.2.

Lot of thanks, for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle we have to use Ref Cursors to acheive this.  The very latest version of ODP .Net supports Ref Cursor binding for Entity Framework 4.x.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20434_01/doc/win.112/e23174/featImplRefCursor.htm).

Of course if you're not using Oracle 11gR2 you're probably out of luck, and you'll need to use one of the other suggestions (such as Pipelined functions).

Answer (score 2):

To return the result of a SELECT in Oracle you would use a "pipelined table function".

Please refer to the manual for a description and an example:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#i53109

Here are some more examples from other sites:

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=207
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/PipelinedTableFunctions.php
http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html

Answer (score 1):

Either create a VIEW or a FUNCTION. Stored procedures in Oracle do not return table results like in TSQL.

Comment: How does the synatx looks for a select returning function?

Comment: See a_horse_with_no_name's answer.